# MVC SelectList not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
if (a)
{
    SelectListItem deliveryItem = new SelectListItem()
    {
        Selected = a.selected,
        Text = "Delivery",
        Value = "1"
    };

    items.Add(deliveryItem);
}

if (b)
{
    SelectListItem pickupItem = new SelectListItem()
    {
        Selected = b.selected,
        Text = "Pickup",
        Value = "2"
    };

    items.Add(pickupItem);
}

SelectList selectList = new SelectList(items);

ViewData["OrderTypeList"] = selectList;
```

**Then using it with**

```
Html.DropDownList("OrderTypeList")
```

**Renders**

```
<select id="OrderTypeList" name="OrderTypeList"><option>System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem</option>
<option>System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem</option>
</select>
```

Why it is not rendering options properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The constructor method you're calling when you do:

```
SelectList selectList = new SelectList(items);
```

Creates a set of SelectListItems that themselves point to SelectListItems (hence the weird option since it just calls ToString on the object). Instead set your list to the ViewData key directly

```
ViewData["OrderTypeList"] = items;
```

Answer (score 7):

You could have also simply changed the one line from:

```
SelectList selectList = new SelectList(items);
```

to

```
SelectList selectList = new SelectList(items, "Text", "Value");
```

This will instruct MVC which properties to use as the `Text` and `Value` in your option tags.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could create a class that will hold the select list and then return the class as the views model.  I think that's a much more elegant way of doing it rather than ViewData.

```
public class MyFormViewModel
{
    public SelectList Friends { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your ActionResult

```
MyFormViewModel fvm = new MyFormViewModel();
fvm.Friends = new SelectList(myList, "UserName", "NickName");
```

Then in your view

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("ToUserName", Model.Friends, new { @class = "field" })%>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Intellisense for the SelectList constructor overloads, the code SelectList(items) should work, but doesn't.  The fact that it simply does a ToString() on items is, as far as I can tell, a bug that Microsoft should fix.  The answers are all nice workarounds. BTW, if you use the method supplying "Text" and "Value", the correct answer should be

```
 SelectList selectList = new SelectList(items, "Value", "Text")
```

not

```
SelectList selectList = new SelectList(items, "Text", "Value")
```

At least, that agrees with my experimentation in MVC 3.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try rendering with

```
Html.DropDownList("OrderTypeList", ViewData["OrderTypeList"])
```

Comment: I think i can use that if i have selectlist in viewdata. But here i am trying to build selectlist